# How to find the maximum misalignment from vibration?

Tags: modeling, vibration

Consider the system in the (drawn in Paint) image. Assume that there is an input acceleration at the ground defined by a PSD. This acceleration can be in any axis. Points A and B are initially aligned and just offset vertically. You are shining a laser through them and need to know what the maximum possible misalignment is to make sure your optics can handle it.

[image]

So, if I have an FEM model, I can find the displacement PSD's in each direction at both points. However, these PSD's are still a stochastic representation of the displacement. I have a few questions because of that:

1. Do the output PSD's represent some confidence interval? Or are they the same level of confidence as the input? (i.e. if the input is an envelope describing the maximum possible input acceleration, this describes the maximum possible output displacement)
2. What features of the PSD can be used to decide a maximum? Does the RMS describe this? And in that case, would it be $rms_{A} + rms_B = disp_{max}$ because each could be off by that much in the worst case? Then, you'd do some vector addition to account for the multiple directions of misalignment to get an absolute misalignment.